# Scala MapReduce Framework giving Type Mismatch

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MapReduce framework in Scala that is based on several o fthe org.apache.hadoop libraries.  It works great with a simple wordcount program.  However, I want to apply it to something useful and am hitting a roadblock. I want to take a csv file (or any delimiter really) and pass whatever is in the 1st column as the key and subsequently count the incidence of keys.

The mapper code looks like this

```
class WordCountMapper extends Mapper[LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable] with HImplicits {
  protected override def map(lnNumber: LongWritable, line: Text, context: Mapper[LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable]#Context): Unit = {
  line.split(",", -1)(0) foreach (context.write(_,1))  //Splits data
  }
}
```

The problem comes in the 'line.split' code.  When I try to compile it, I get an error that says:

found: char
required:org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.

line.split... should return a string that is being passed to the _ in the write(_,1), but for soem reason itis thinking it is a char.  I've even added .toString to explicitly make it a string but that didn't work either.

Any ideas are appreciated.  Let me know what additional details I can provide.

Update:

Here is the list of imports:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, Text}
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.{Reducer, Job, Mapper}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.{Configured}
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import org.apache.hadoop.util.{ToolRunner, Tool}
```

Here is the build.sbt code:

```
import AssemblyKeys._ // put this at the top of the file

assemblySettings

organization := "scala"

name := "WordCount"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion:= "2.11.2"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-no-specialization", "-deprecation")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "1.2.1",
                        "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "latest.integration" exclude ("hadoop-core", "org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocol/ClientDatanodeProtocol.class") ,
                        "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.5.1",
                        "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core" % "2.5.1",
                        "commons-configuration" % "commons-configuration" % "1.9",
                        "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "latest.integration")


 jarName in assembly := "WordCount.jar"

 mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
  {case s if s.endsWith(".class") => MergeStrategy.last
case s if s.endsWith(".xsd") => MergeStrategy.last
case s if s.endsWith(".dtd") => MergeStrategy.last
case s if s.endsWith(".xml") => MergeStrategy.last
case s if s.endsWith(".properties") => MergeStrategy.last
case x => old(x)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your imports and your build.sbt or list of dependencies so I can try to compile it?

Comment: `line` is a "Hadoop Writable" `Text`, you *need* to call `toString` to get a Java String out of it which supports split. You should tell us the error you get when you do this call.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut , do you mean use "line.split(",",-1)(0).toString"?  That produces the same error mentioned above.

Comment: @EricZoerner I added the info you requested.  Let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: @JCalbreath no, I added an answer. `line` needs to be a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this by not using the _ notation and just directly specifying the value in context.write.  So instead of:

```
line.split(",", -1)(0) foreach (context.write(_,1))
```

I used:

```
context.write(line.split(",", -1)(0), 1)
```

I found a item online that said sometime Scala gets confused on data types when using the _, and recommending just explicitly defining the value in place.  Not sure if that is true, but it solved the problem in this case.

Comment: Nothing to do with `_`, everything to do with no longer unnecessarily calling `foreach`.

Comment: That makes sense.  I guess was thinking that because it was only passing one string (the 0th item) that it didn't matter and would just iterate once over that one item.  But I guess it was iterating over each character in that one string.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `line` is implicitly converted to `String` here (thanks to `HImplicits`?).  Then we have

```
line.split(",", -1)(0) foreach somethigOrOther
```

- split the string into multiple strings - `.split(...)`
- take the zeroth of these strings - `(0)`
- then iterate `somethingOrOther` **over the characters** of that string - `foreach`

Thus you get your `char`.